# React HTML-Component, input style radio - checked

Tags: html, reactjs, radio-button, checked

I have 2 radio button, (input type radio),i used "checked" on the second, now, if i want to check the first radio button i need to click twice, how di i fix it ??

```html
<label>YES</label> <input type={'radio'} name={'license'}/><br />
<label>NO</label> <input type={'radio'} name={'license'} checked={'checked'}/>
```

Comment: This isn't valid HTML. Are you using React?

Comment: yes i forgot to mention it, how do i edit my question ?

Comment: You click the link marked "Edit"

Comment: forget i asked it..... can you help me about it ??

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless.

Answer (score 0):

You are using *uncontrolled* inputs, so the React rendering cycle is interfering with the user modified state of the DOM.

If you continue using uncontrolled inputs, use `defaultChecked` and not `checked`. (See [default values](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values).)

[Controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) are recommended in most cases though.

Comment: Thank you <3, i just saw "checked" everywhere i was searching for, "defaultChecked" is exactly what i was looking for.